# How can I set focus on a dynamically added field with React

Tags: reactjs

I have a basic task list app that gives users the ability to add items to the task list. When the "Add Item" button is clicked I will insert a new row to the bottom of the list. The row contains an empty text field, where the user can enter their task name. I want to set the focus on this field as soon as it's `push()`ed into the array. I know how to set the focus using a `ref` if the field already exists, but I can't seem to figure it out for a dynamically added field. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
const tasks = [array_of_task_objects];
const [state, setState] = React.useState({tasks: tasks});
const newTask = {title: ''};

const addTask = () => {
    let newTasks = [...state.tasks];
    newTasks.push(newTask);
    setState({...state, tasks: newTasks});
    // Now, set focus in the input field...(how?)
};
```

Elsewhere:

```
<button onClick={addTask}>Add Task</button>

<ul>
    {
        state.tasks.map(task => {
            return(
                <li><input value={task.title}></li>
            );
        })
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the task input focus itself when it is rendered the first time.

```js
const Task = ({value}) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => if (ref.current) {ref.current.focus()}, [ref.current])

  return <li><input ref={ref} value={value} /></li>
}
```

This will work if you are only mounting one at a time. If you have multiple inputs rendered in an initial state for example you could introduce a `shouldTakeFocus` prop. Then you limit  the effect to only run when `shouldTakeFocus` is true.

Comment: Wouldn't ```ref.current``` always evaluate to ```true``` for every Task component that renders? If so, and assuming there are no race conditions, then it seems that the last Task component to render would always have its focus set. Is this correct?

Comment: On the very first render ref.current will be `null` the second render ref.current will be the the ref of the element. I'm not sure how it would be affected by race conditions.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to have a ref that's always referring to the last textbox and then running an effect that sets focus on that last element when `tasks` are updated. This is a shell of an example that should basically get you there:

```
export default function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([newTask]);
  const lastRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (lastRef.current)
      lastRef.current.focus();
  }, [tasks]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {tasks.map((task, i) => (
        <>
          <input key={i} ref={i === tasks.length - 1 ? lastRef : undefined} />
          <br />
        </>
      ))}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setTasks(tasks => [...tasks, newTask]);
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```